# Problems printing a bitmap font

Tags: c, fonts, bitmap

Lately I'm trying to print a bitmap font in C, using only a set_pixel function (that only sets the color of a pixel in a determinate coordinate of the screen).
The problem is that when I try my code, this code does not work at all. 
I will write the code down, do you know why this is failing?
The only reason I could find is a warning that my compiler (clang) reports:

```
x86_64-uefi/tty.c:67:11: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion passing 'char [2]' to parameter of type 'char' [-Wint-conversion]
        put_char("c", 1, 1, r | g | b);
```

That I don't know how to fix.

Files involved:
 1: tty.c (The one that prints)

```
#include "font.h"
#include "tty.h"
KABI void put_char(char c, uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint32_t rgb) 
{
    uint8_t i,j;

    // Convert the character to an index
    c = c & 0x7F;
    if (c < ' ') {
        c = 0;
    } else {
        c -= ' ';
    }

    // 'font' is a multidimensional array of [96][char_width]
    // which is really just a 1D array of size 96*char_width.
    const uint8_t* chr = font[c*CHAR_WIDTH];

    // Draw pixels
    for (j=0; j<CHAR_WIDTH; j++) {
        for (i=0; i<CHAR_HEIGHT; i++) {
            if (chr[j] & (1<<i)) {
                set_pixel(x+j, y+i, rgb);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

2: tty.h (the header of tty.c)

```
#pragma once

// Types (uint8_t, etc.)
#include "typedefs.h"

// tty_init: Cleans the screen and setup all.
KABI void tty_init(void);

KABI void put_char(char c, uint8_t x, uint8_t y, uint32_t rgb);
```

3: font.h (I made it a little bit shorter)

```
// Our types (uint8_t, etc.)
#include "typedefs.h"
#define CHAR_WIDTH 6
#define CHAR_HEIGHT 8
const unsigned char font[96][6] = {
    {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, //  
    {0x2e,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // !
    {0x03,0x00,0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // "
    {0x0a,0x1f,0x0a,0x1f,0x0a,0x00}, // #
    {0x2e,0x2a,0x6b,0x2a,0x3a,0x00}, // $
    {0x0e,0x2a,0x1e,0x08,0x3c,0x2a}, // %
    {0x3e,0x2a,0x2a,0x22,0x38,0x08}, // &
    {0x03,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}, // '
...
    {0x3e,0x24,0x24,0x24,0x3c,0x00}, // b
    {0x3c,0x24,0x24,0x24,0x24,0x00}, // c
...
    {0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00}
};
```

Calling the tty_init function output the following:
[image]
Apparently nothing, but if you take a closer look (the font is pretty small), it prints just a line of 6 pixels, 
Thanks in advance!

I don't know if it has something to do, but...

Notes: `KABI` stands for `__attribute__((sysv_abi))`
and the pixel line is printed at the top of the "represented" string.

Comment: Too easy, sorry... The warning is correct. `put_char("c", ...` – you feed it a *string address* and not a single character code `'c'`. So you get the bitmap of some high number, out of range for your character definitions.

Comment: The prototype of the set_pixel function is the following: `set_pixel(int x, int y, uint32_t rgb)`

Comment: Changing "c" with 'c' as you suggest have no effect, the "ghost mark" disappears, but the output stays black.

Comment: Well there you go. Are you sure you can "add" `r | g | b` from plain colors as you did? Or did you remember to shift them into the right positions beforehand? If not, maybe your pixels are too dark. In case of doubt, hardcode full white in your function.

Comment: Calling the `set_pixel` separately function with exactly the same colors in the same position outputs the intended color (grey) without problems, but I will try the bright white in a moment

Comment: Mmmm... I see you defined the characters rotated clockwise. I don't think the putpixel order is a problem after all.

Comment: This code is part of a little project I have in github, despite the project needs compilation and an emulator (is a little operative system), maybe is useful to see the code in more context, if you find it useful, here is the code: https://github.com/TheStr3ak5/CKA , the involved files are https://github.com/TheStr3ak5/CKA/blob/master/kernel/arch/x86_64-uefi/tty.c https://github.com/TheStr3ak5/CKA/blob/master/kernel/arch/x86_64-uefi/font.h https://github.com/TheStr3ak5/CKA/blob/master/kernel/includes/tty.h uefi directory, if not, just ignore this message.

Comment: Indeed, changing output color to 255/255/255 in rgb code (white) had no effect, the output still without showing